# which is more efficient: use default binding value or assign a value on inserting data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, binding, sql-insert

A general question for inserting tons of data into DB.

I like to know which one will work faster.

Plan A:

table structure:

```
some Data columns  ....
Date_Added  DataTime
```

Import program:

```
insert data with  Date_Added assigned.
Date_Added = datetime.now
```

Plan B

table structure:

```
some Data columns  ....
Date_Added  DataTime binding value  getdate()
```

Import program:

```
insert data without  Date_Added.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a big long for a comment.

As with most questions about performance, you should try it on your data on your system.  But I doubt it makes any difference.

Inserting data into a database involves a bunch of operations:

- Starting/ending a transaction
- Finding at least one free data page, perhaps loading it into the page cache or perhaps allocating a new one
- Logging the transaction
- Checking constraints
- Running triggers
- Structuring data to copy onto the data page
- Updating indexes

And probably a bunch of other things as well.  In the context of all this work, the additional work for looking a default value versus having one available in the insert seems negligible.